# How to get related object in Subsonic 3 (ActiveRecord)?

Tags: activerecord, subsonic3

Given the following:

class Customer
  string name
end

class Order
  int number
end

I am creating a list of orders. For each order listed, i'd like to display the associated customer name. is there a way to do that via the object graph, or do I have to look it up manually?

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a relation parent-child, Subsonic will honour it, then:

```
for each o as Order in orders
   Console.WriteLine(o.Customers(0).name)
next
```